# Chain equality operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, equality

I have a question about how chain equality works in JavaScript.

For example in python if you have:
`a, b = 1, 2`
`a == b == False    //False`
Because it converts to:
`(a == b) and (b == False)`
So, finally it is False.

But when I try this in js:
`console.log(1==2==false)    // true`

I got "true". I don't know why and how it is worked in js.
could you please help me out?

Comment: any operator could be chained ...

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to chain equality or relational operators that way in JavaScript (or most other languages in my experience, but particularly JavaScript). Use `&&` or `||`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes. I think Python is one of the very few exceptions where chaining works, e.g. `10 < x < 20` is evaluated as `10 < x && x < 20`. However, as I said, Python is in the minority there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading left to right:

`1==2` is false

`false==false` is true

Answer (score 3):

in the code `1 == 2 == false`

we read it as `1 == 2` == `false`

so basically `1 == 2` is `false`

and `fasle == false` is `true`